# How do I get find_all to work in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web page using Python and BeautifulSoup. I have tried different combinations, but my code only retrieves the first item from the webpage even though I can see 52 on the screen and in the HTML. I am guessing that somehow there is a hierarchy to the HTML that I do not understand and the example I have copied did not have that setup. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

sample_page = "http://www.huntingtonbrass.com/intrigue-single-control-single-handle-faucet-w3160001-1.html"

page = requests.get(sample_page)

print(page.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

product_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-name')

print(type(product_containers))
print(len(product_containers))
print(product_containers)
```

The HTML can be found at the address shown above. I am trying to get a list of all of the products and have been searching on product name. I will catch on pretty quickly if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: When I look at the source code of that page, I see only one `div` tag with `class="product-name"`. Your code seems to work correctly. The remaining occurrences of `class="product-name"` are for `h3` tags (and there are only 3, not 52).

Comment: Thanks. I used the search function (cntrl F) in chrome on product-name and it reports that there are 52. Not sure i understand how to combine h2 and class  name into a single search. Thanks for your assistance.